# How to override field before saving it in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a class User in `models.py`:

```
class User(models.Model):
    userId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, blank=False, max_length=100)
```

The `userId` always comes with a prefix `user#` and I have not been able to query one user from the db when there is `#`. If I understood correctly, that is not even possible so now I've tried to modify the save method so that the `userId` would be saved without the `user#` prefix. I tried this under the User class:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    userId = self.userId[5:]
    print("USER_ID: ", userId)
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That prints the id correctly, without the prefix but in the database the `userId` is still saved with it. Is there something wrong with my save -method?

Comment: It's an instance attribute, so you should use `self.userId = ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save it to the `self.userId`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.userId.startswith('user#'):
        self.userId = self.userId[5:]
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The prefix check is necessary, since otherwise you will remove the first five characters *each* time you save the object, and as a result, eventually the string will be empty.

That being said, the Django ORM does not always call `.save(…)` to save an object. Indeed, a lot of operations to create/update items in bulk will not call the user.

If I query the object with a hash (`#`), it returns the correct item:

```
>>> User.objects.create(userId='foo#bar')
<User: User object (1)>
NameError: name 'Unit' is not defined
>>> User.objects.filter(userId='foo#bar')
<QuerySet [<User: User object (1)>]>
```